# Elasticsearch: How to get documents without index

Tags: elasticsearch

I had to deleted an ES index.

My question is: all docs in the deleted index were deleted too? If no, how I can reindex the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v
```

and check if the index was indeed removed. If it's not on the list, then you are not able to reindex the data - deleting an index means deleting the corresponding files/directories.

For the future, use [Aliases for indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) in order to easily switch between the old and the new index, keeping the possibility to reindex the data, or use [Snapshot module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) to create snapshots of your indices.

Comment: Hi @Joanna, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately my index was indeed removed, it's so bad.